# getting results back with Selenium and Python on Clutch.co - see some interesting output

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to use Python with BeautifulSoup to scrape information from the Clutch.co website.

I want to collect data from companies that are listed at clutch.co :: lets take for example the it agencies from israel that are visible on clutch.co:

https://clutch.co/il/agencies/digital

while the target - clutch.co is working with robot.txt - i choose a selenium approach:
see my approach!?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def scrape_clutch_digital_agencies_with_selenium(url):
    # Set up Chrome options for headless browsing
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode

    # Create a Chrome webdriver instance
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    # Visit the URL
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the JavaScript challenge to be completed (adjust sleep time if needed)
    time.sleep(5)

    # Get the page source after JavaScript has executed
    page_source = driver.page_source

    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

    # Find the elements containing agency names (adjust this based on the website structure)
    agency_name_elements = soup.select('.company-info .company-name')

    # Extract and print the agency names
    agency_names = [element.get_text(strip=True) for element in agency_name_elements]

    print("Digital Agencies in Israel:")
    for name in agency_names:
        print(name)

    # Close the webdriver
    driver.quit()

# Example usage
url = 'https://clutch.co/il/agencies/digital'
scrape_clutch_digital_agencies_with_selenium(url)
```

see what comes back as a  result - in google-colab:

```
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-a29f326dd68b> in <cell line: 41>()
     39 # Example usage
     40 url = 'https://clutch.co/il/agencies/digital'
---> 41 scrape_clutch_digital_agencies_with_selenium(url)

6 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    227                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x565c2a694f83 <unknown>
#1 0x565c2a34dcf7 <unknown>
#2 0x565c2a38560e <unknown>
#3 0x565c2a38226e <unknown>
#4 0x565c2a3d280c <unknown>
#5 0x565c2a3c6e53 <unknown>
#6 0x565c2a38edd4 <unknown>
#7 0x565c2a3901de <unknown>
#8 0x565c2a659531 <unknown>
#9 0x565c2a65d455 <unknown>
#10 0x565c2a645f55 <unknown>
#11 0x565c2a65e0ef <unknown>
#12 0x565c2a62999f <unknown>
#13 0x565c2a682008 <unknown>
#14 0x565c2a6821d7 <unknown>
```

i am working on a correction - so that this scraper works well on the example:

https://clutch.co/il/agencies/digital